# Ошибка при генерации id

Tags: java, postgresql, pgadmin4, pgadmin

Когда я сохраняю данные, оставляю `id` пустым, чтобы pgAdmin заполнил их сам. После этого выходит ошибка:

```
Column "id" is an identity column defined as generated always.cannot insert a non -DEFAULT value into column "id"
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: *когда я сохраняю данные* Как именно? *id оставляю пустым* Вы передаёте пустую строку, NULL? или вообще не указываете это поле в INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

Установите id primary key, serial. После чего во время добавления строки добавляйте следующим образом.

```
INSERT INTO table(completed,task_date ...) VALUES(value,value ...)
```

Надеюсь ответ порешит вашу проблему. Если нет, дайте побольше информации.